# Insert ISODate in Mongodb with milliseconds

Tags: php, mongodb, isodate

I'm running PHP 7 with the php_mongodb-1.2.2-7.0-nts-vc14-x64 driver.

```
$ar = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2017-07-27 06:17:25.123000') * 1000);
```

Output of above statement is:

> ISODate("2017-07-27T06:17:25.000+0000")

but I need milliseconds also like:

> ISODate("2017-07-27T06:17:25.123+0000")

Since I'm so new I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` do not support milliseconds.

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into
>   a Unix timesta

So the `strtotime('2017-07-27 06:17:25.123000')` and `strtotime('2017-07-27 06:17:25')` will return the same result `1501136245`

You must use DateTime:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s u', '2017-07-27 06:17:25 123000');
$ar = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($date->format('U.u'));
```

Comment: so which function to use for milisecond?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
function mongo_current_datetime(){
    $date = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('now') * 1000);
    return $date;
}
```

Example Output:

> MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
> (
> [milliseconds] => 1610972571000
> )

The function above prepares current datetime Object in milliseconds , ready to insert into mongoDB.